# How to create labels once a GUI button is pressed?

Tags: c#, windows, xamarin, label, xamarin-studio

I have a GUI button that can detect when it is pressed and a piece of code that I want to have create labels when the button is pressed. I'm currently converting an entry to an int (This is working. Tested by displaying the int in an entry.) and trying to use a for loop. My code is in the source code of my main window. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using Gtk;

public partial class MainWindow: Gtk.Window
{
public MainWindow () : base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
{
    Build ();
}

protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
{
    Application.Quit ();
    a.RetVal = true;
}

protected void generatePlates (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int n;
    short number;
    bool validNumnber;

    if (Int16.TryParse (entry1.Text, out number))
    {
        validNumnber = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        validNumnber = false;
    }

    if (validNumnber == true)
    {
        n = Int16.Parse(entry1.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        n = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Name = "lbl"+i;
        lbl.Text = "Plate "+i+":";
        lbl.Allocation = new Gdk.Rectangle (110*i+110,110*i+110,100,100);
        this.Add (lbl);

        entry3.Text = this.ToString();
    }
}
```

Any advice is appreciated and feel free to ask for more details. If my code has other flaws in it, please let me know as I am a complete novice. Also `entry3` is just an entry I'm using for testing this.

Edit: This code is for a windows desktop app.

Comment: is this for a Mac desktop app?

Comment: you need to edit your tags to make this more clear.  When people see Xamarin they typically assume you're writing a mobile app, and base their answers on that.  If you're using Xamarin to write a GDK app for Windows, you need to be a lot explicit about that in your question/tags

Comment: I tried this.Add (lbl); but it doesn't work unless I set it to run when the window opens.

Comment: Where exactly is your button click event?  If your code doesn't have confidential information, you can post the code for the entire window here.

Comment: How is generatePlates method being called?  I don't see it being called anywhere.

Comment: Xamarin Studio handles that in the designer where I just assign generatePlates to the button and it automatically calls it when the button is pressed.

Comment: So, you mentioned that it works when you place the label creation in the window opening events... how are you doing that?  Are you using the designer to set generatePlates event there too?

Comment: To test the code for the label I just put it just before the `Build ();` at the start. Now that I think about it that might not actually be the opening of the window.

Comment: What is the Build (); method actually doing?  What happens if you try to call Build (); again after this.add (lbl);

Answer (score 0):

In general, you need to add the new control to the Form/view/whatever's collection of controls.  If you are running this in a view than simply use.
`View.Add (lbl);`

If you are using c#.net winforms (which I don't think you are) then use
`this.Controls.Add(lbl);`

Comment: I'm currently using `this.Add (lbl);`. Is this different to what you're saying. Also the script works when moved to the opening of the window and the `for` loop and button also work. Any ideas why moving the script to the button would stop it from working?

Comment: "this" refers to the context of the class.  So if you are within the View class then "this" refers to the view object.  However, if you are in another class, "this" refers to that class object.  If you are unsure, just break your code at that line and check the value of "this".  Also, are you sure your button click event is firing?

Comment: I'm sure that the button event is firing because I tested it with this:
    entry3.Text = entry3.Text + "TEST ";
Not sure how to check the value of "this".

Comment: you can display this.ToString()   You may be able to use this.Name, but only if that class object has a Name property.  So, it's better to use ToString().  There are other easier ways to get this, but I'm not sure outside of the VS ISE.

Comment: When I try `entry3.Text = this.ToString();` in my `for` loop it shows MainWindow. Doesn't this mean that `this.Add (lbl);` should work even when inside the `for` loop?

Comment: It means that "this" is your MainWindow object.  Is this the same in both the button click event and the window open you mentioned? I'm not sure I can be of much more help, as I don't know the Xamarin environment much.

Comment: Perhaps you could post more of your code so other users can get the full scope of the issue.